# passing css to new page using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a string comparer using `diffjs` library and want to display the resultant table in a new page using `javascript`.

Although I can see the table on a new window and also able to passed the css and js script on the new window (as they are there in the inspect element tab of the browser) but till css is not working and I see only plain text.

I have used  `w.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssNode);`to pass css and respective javascripts to pass js and css to new window

Comment: Instead of passing it to the new page, if the css is only going to represent the data, just keep it in the target page from the beginning instead of passing it....

Comment: i havent made a new page.just using window.open().document.body.html('html of populated table to send') to open a new window with data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure,but maybe wrap it into style tags.

```
w.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild("<style>"+cssNode+"</style>");
```